# hash map as unique value store / instance counter. java

Tags: java, search, hashmap, nlp, bigdata

I'm trying to create a program to learn rules by inference,  i.e. `'contains'('vitamin c', 'oranges').`, `'prevents'('scurvy', 'vitamin c').` would yield the output "rule" `'prevents'('scurvy', 'oranges').` I have code which will produce that output but then I wanted to eliminate duplicate "rules" from the input while keeping track of the number of times they were observed (as a naive confidence measure, since frequently observed rules are more likely to be true), so I implemented a hash map which stores the "rule" as a key and the number of observed instances as the value. However it seems the hash map is not functioning correctly and I'm at a loss as to the reason for this behaviour, perhaps someone more knowledgeable than I might be able to spot it.

Machine learning component architecture:

```
private List<Sentence> sentences = new ArrayList<>();
/*
 * The following maps store the relation of a string occurring
 * as a subject or object, respectively, to the list of Sentence
 * ordinals where they occur.
 */
private Map<String,List<Integer>> subject2index = new HashMap<>();
private Map<String,List<Integer>> object2index = new HashMap<>();

/*
 * This set contains strings that occur as both,
 * subject and object. This is useful for determining strings
 * acting as an in-between connecting two relations. 
 */
private Set<String> joints = new HashSet<>();

public void addSentence( Sentence s )
{

    // add Sentence to the list of all Sentences
    sentences.add( s );

    // add the Subject of the Sentence to the map mapping strings
    // occurring as a subject to the ordinal of this Sentence
    List<Integer> subind = subject2index.get( s.getSubject() );
    if( subind == null )
    {
        subind = new ArrayList<>();
        subject2index.put( s.getSubject(), subind );
    }
    subind.add( sentences.size() - 1 );

    // add the Object of the Sentence to the map mapping strings
    // occurring as an object to the ordinal of this Sentence
    List<Integer> objind = object2index.get( s.getObject() );
    if( objind == null )
    {
        objind = new ArrayList<>();
        object2index.put( s.getObject(), objind );
    }
    objind.add( sentences.size() - 1 );

    // determine whether we've found a "joining" string
    if( subject2index.containsKey( s.getObject() ) )
    {
        joints.add( s.getObject() );
    }
    if( object2index.containsKey( s.getSubject() ) )
    {
        joints.add( s.getSubject() );
    }
}

public Collection<String> getJoints()
{
    return joints;
}
public List<Integer> getSubjectIndices( String subject )
{
    return subject2index.get( subject );
}
public List<Integer> getObjectIndices( String object )
{
    return object2index.get( object );
}
public Sentence getSentence( int index )
{
    return sentences.get( index );
}
```

Hash map for storing only unique copies and number of occurances:

```
//map to store learned 'rules'
Map<Sentence, Integer> ruleCount = new HashMap<>();
//store data
public void numberRules(Sentence sentence) 
{
    if (!ruleCount.containsKey(sentence))
    {
        ruleCount.put(sentence, 0);
    }
    ruleCount.put(sentence, ruleCount.get(sentence) + 1);
}
```

The object Sentence:

```
public class Sentence 
{
private String verb;
private String object;
private String subject;
public Sentence(String verb, String object, String subject )
{
    this.verb = verb;
    this.object = object;
    this.subject = subject;
}

public String getVerb()
{
    return verb; 
}

public String getObject()
{
    return object; 
}

public String getSubject()
{
    return subject;
}

public String toString()
{
    return verb + "(" + object + ", " + subject + ").";
}

}
```

Current input:

```
'prevents'('scurvy', 'vitamin C').
'contains'('vitamin C', 'orange').
'contains'('vitamin C', 'sauerkraut').
'is a'('fruit', 'orange').
'improves'('health', 'fruit').
'contains'('vitamin C', 'orange').
'improves'('health', 'fruit').
```

Current output:

```
prevents(scurvy, orange). : 1
improves(health, orange). : 1
prevents(scurvy, orange). : 1
prevents(scurvy, sauerkraut). : 1
improves(health, orange). : 1
```

Desired output:

```
prevents(scurvy, orange). : 2
improves(health, orange). : 2
prevents(scurvy, sauerkraut). : 1
```

Code that executes:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException 
{


    Ontology ontology = new Ontology();
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("file.txt"));
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("'(.*?)'\\('(.*?)',\\s*'(.*?)'\\)\\.");
    String line;
    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) 
    {
        Matcher m = p.matcher(line);
        if( m.matches() ) 
        {
            String verb    = m.group(1);
            String object  = m.group(2);
            String subject = m.group(3);
            ontology.addSentence( new Sentence( verb, object, subject ) );
        }
    }

    for( String joint: ontology.getJoints() )
    {
        for( Integer subind: ontology.getSubjectIndices( joint ) )
        {
            Sentence xaS = ontology.getSentence( subind );

            for( Integer obind: ontology.getObjectIndices( joint ) )
            {

                Sentence yOb = ontology.getSentence( obind );

                Sentence s = new Sentence( xaS.getVerb(),
                                           xaS.getObject(),
                                           yOb.getSubject() );

                //System.out.println( s );                
                ontology.numberRules( s );    

            }
        }
    }
    for (Map.Entry<Sentence, Integer> entry : ontology.ruleCount.entrySet()) 
    {
        System.out.println(entry.getKey()+" : "+entry.getValue());
    }       
}
```

As an aside, when I run this on a large file I get an OutOfMemory: Java heap space error and the program crashes. I know I can increase the size of the heap but that seems like a poor solution. How could I optimize the efficiency of this code to enable it to process large data sets?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I suggested in your previous question, you should override `hashCode` and `equals` in your `Sentence` class, since the default behavior implemented in `Object` class doesn't suit your needs.

```
@Override
boolean equals (Object other)
{
    if (!(other instanceof Sentence))
        return false;
    if (other == this)
        return true;
    Sentence o = (Sentence) other;
    return o.subject.equals(subject) && o.object.equals(object) && o.verb.equals(verb);
}

@Override
public int hashCode ()
{
    return Objects.hash(object, subject, verb); // this method only exists since Java 7
}
```

When you use one of your custom classes as a key in a `HashMap` (as you do with the `Sentence` class), you must override `equals()` and `hashCode()`. If you don't override them, `a.equals(b)` will return true only if `a==b`, which is probably not the behavior you desire.

You want `a.equals(b)` to return true when the verb, object and subject of the two compared `Sentence`s are equal to each other respectively. Otherwise, two sentences that you consider to be identical may be considered by `HashMap` to be distinct keys.

`hashCode()` should be implemented to match the implementation of `equals`, in a way that if `a.equals(b)` is true, `a.hashCode() == b.hashCode()` is also true. That's why the `hashCode` should be a function of the 3 properties of your `Sentence` class.